# Change elapsed time after a month to different format

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I am using codeigniter and I have this code below It converts date in to a elapsed time to something like `Asked 1 month, 3 weeks ago`

If the date is older than a month I would like it to only display like date `Asked Sept 01 05:34:13` and  if older than a year `Asked Sept 01 2015 05:34:13`

**Currently if time is under month prints out like below which is fine**

**example** Asked 1 minute, 14 seconds ago

**example** Asked 2 weeks, 3 hours ago

```
$this->when_was_question_posted(strtotime('2016-09-01 05:34:13'))
```

> Question how can I make sure that if the date is older than a month
>   then display like date `Asked Sept 01 05:34:13` and if older than a
>   year `Asked Sept 01 2015 05:34:13`

```
function when_was_question_posted($distant_timestamp, $max_units = 2) {
    $i = 0;
    $time = time() - $distant_timestamp; // to get the time since that moment

    $tokens = [
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    ];

    $responses = [];

    while ($i < $max_units) {
        foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
            if ($time < $unit) {
                continue;
            }
            $i++;
            $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);

            $responses[] = $numberOfUnits . ' ' . $text . (($numberOfUnits > 1) ? 's' : '');
            $time -= ($unit * $numberOfUnits);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($responses)) {
        return 'Asked ' . implode(', ', $responses) . ' ago';
    }

    return 'Just now';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you ever played with php's datetime class. It might be worth a look at.

Comment: I have only used date like `echo date('d-m-y)` not explored it fully yet. would not know how to do it with the code above

Comment: Have a look to: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: What if the date is less than a month? You've not specified that and I'm too lazy to work it out from your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you going...

```
$date_now = new DateTime();
$date     = new DateTime('2014-04-01 00:00:00');

$interval = $date_now->diff($date);

if($interval->y > 0) {
    echo "More than a year";
    echo "<br>";
    $display_date = $date->format('M d Y h:i:s');
} elseif($interval->m > 0) {
    echo "More than a month";
    echo "<br>";
    $display_date = $date->format('M d h:i:s');
} else {
    // Call your existing function
}
```